# How to forbid one directory only in TOMOYO (2.5)?

Tags: linux, mandatory-access-control

(For example) I want to restrict write access to `/home/backup` from anybody, *except* a particular backup script. (To protect from accidental deletion.) For this, I suppose, it is enough to have two domains: `<kernel>` and `</usr/bin/backup-script>`. And I need to enable for `<kernel>` access to everything **except** write access to `/home/backup`. How to do that exception? I don't see exclusion rules in TOMOYO policy specification, and the general ideology of TOMOYO is only granting access, not forbidding.

Answer (score 1):

Acutally no need to exclude kernel.
You can tell though files `/home/backup/\*{\*}\*` may only be changed if domain `"<kernel> /usr/bin/backup-script"` does access.

relevant links from Tomoyo Guide:

- http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/2.5/policy-specification/exception-policy-syntax.html.en#path_group
- [Chapter 5-8](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/2.5/index.html.en)

Comment: Problem is how to *forbid* other processes (besides backup) write access to backup data. All processes should have full access *anywhere* **except** `/home/backup/\*{\*}\*`. There is no problem allowing access to backup data for backup script, since in TOMOYO you granting accesss (and only granting).

Comment: If you apply and Enforce a policy for a specific domain you will achive exaclty what you want. Sorry cant explain better -.-

Comment: I need to restrict <kernel> do you understand that? I **can not** just add `/\*{\*}\*` and exclude `/home/backup/\*{\*}\*`, I **should** only add all dirs, excluding `/home/\*{\*}\*`, than in `/home` I should explicitly add every dirs of users, except `/home/backup/\*{\*}\*`. That is tons of rules already. And then every time I add user I should add rule for him. All that fun because TOMOYO is lacking *exclusion* rules.

Answer (score 0):

Tomoyo has some kind of exclusion:

/home/*-backup is what you need

http://tomoyo.osdn.jp/2.5/policy-specification/expression-rules.html.en#wildcard